# How to have a super user using Spring Security Framework?

Tags: spring-security

I am using [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) to control the authority in my web application.I imported the **security** tag in my code as below:
`<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>`
Then I am using the code block like this to control if the user have access to the specified button:

```html
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="addUser">
     <button type="button">Add User</button>
</sec:authorize>
```

With this code,only the user who have the **addUser** authority can see this button and use it.

Now my question is:**Can we have a super user that even if it doesn't have the addUser authority,he still can see this button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think there is such feature built-in in Spring Security. You can either:

1. have a super user role (authority) that you check for in every authorization check, or
2. give your super user all possible authorities in your authentication provider or user details service.

Comment: Yes,I used the second solution to do it,although it's not a good solution,but I still need to thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that it is the expected answer, but SpringSecurity has a notion of hierachy of roles. That mean you could create a super user role and declare it to contain `addUser` authority (among others).

That way, any user having the `superUser` authority will (among other permissions) see your button

References : From [Hierarchical Roles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/authz-arch.html#authz-hierarchical-roles) in Spring Security reference manual you could write something like

```
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_SUPER_USER > ROLE_ADD_USER
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Before I post my question to stackoverflow I have searched it on google and find the Hierarchical Roles,but it's not meet my demand,because when use this I need to write all the authorities into the spring xml configuration file,but the authorites are too much and they are stored in the database!

Comment: @lucumt A custom super user voter could be a solution. I'll elaborate on it in a while if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a missing requirement, thus I have created an issue in Spring Security repository:

https://github.com/spring-guides/top-spring-security-architecture/issues/5